# Plastic and oil eating microbes apocalypse part 1 - How fast can they spread?

Tags: biology, apocalypse, ocean

Plastic is a huge problem in our lives. One of the ideas is to engineer plastic eating [bacteria](https://www.popsci.com/bacteria-enzyme-plastic-waste) or [fungi](https://www.sci-techuniverse.com/2018/12/a-fungus-that-can-eat-plastic-has-been.html). Experiments already begun, and accidents already happen:

> a team of international scientists illustrate how they created—by accident—a new enzyme capable of breaking down plastic bottles.

So let's assume microbe like that was engineered to just eat plastic like it eats sugars and other stuff. Then, containment broke in processing plants next to [ten rivers that contribute the most to plastic problems](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/stemming-the-plastic-tide-10-rivers-contribute-most-of-the-plastic-in-the-oceans/):

1. Yangtze
2. Indus
3. Yellow
4. Hai
5. Nile
6. Ganges
7. Pearl
8. Amur
9. Niger
10. Mekong

How fast can we get this microbes all around the oceans, especially plastic deposits? They will be almost unchallenged on food, because hardly anything else in nature eats plastic, so all real life models look irrelevant to me. On the other hand, I'm not sure if I can just use speed of ocean currents - and if I can, simulating it is above my knowledge at the moment.

You can give this microbe any advantage needed, I want it everywhere as fast as possible to make my apocalypse sudden, and to make world unable to stop it.

---

Note: 
This question does not touch things that are not relevant to rapidity of spreading. It avoids them on purpose, they will be worked upon in parts 2, 3 and possibly more. Now, if there is something missing about how fast could it spread in oceans, I'll be glad to work on this question. If it belongs to follow ups, please wait.

Comment: I would just keep in mind that being unchallenged for food doesn't mean being invincible, bacteriophages, other micro-organisms, even plants and fungi all have ways to kill microbes in their environment (for example all the natural antiobitics we've discovered)

Comment: @Thymine good point, and one more reason for me to not know how fast it could happen.

Comment: Engineered to eat plastic does not translate to imunne to osmosis, nor immune to plankton and filter feeders eating it.

Comment: @Renan I never said it does. But being a single cell makes it pretty immune to filter feeders, doesn't it?

Comment: @Mołot I think you're right.

Comment: Here are some [plastic quantity estimates](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9003/how-much-garbage-goes-into-the-pacific-ocean-every-year/9023#9023), from ES.SE.

Comment: @kingledion Thank you - this will be useful for art 2 - how fast can my microbes actually eat it up.

Comment: Why is this an apocalypse? It will eat plastic, then when the plastic runs out, it will die. Assuming the bacterial colonies are biodegradeable, they'll become a source of nutrients for algae and decomposers. Where is the problem?

Comment: @nzaman it also eats oil. So it will eat insulation from electric cables, plastic water pipes that are so popular now, window frames, computer cases, and oil reserves we could use to re-make all that stuff. And then it'll continue to eat traditional stuff, competing with other bacteria or fungi, but having a huge head-start.

Comment: If the microbe is omnivorous enough to eat both, say, PVC and styrene, then seems like it would be no trouble to eat chlorophyll and many other non-plastic organic compounds, too. One hopes the microbe has a ready weakness (UV, pH, etc) or it's bigger than a puny human apocalypse.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for neat idea - I probably will use it in next questions of this series ;)

Comment: The engineered nanotech/biotech plagues in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_51_(novel) are worth a read on this topic. What this misses is the extent to which living things are made from polymers, e.g. cellulose and keratin.

Comment: @Catalyst this is the first question on this topic. It doesn't "miss" things that are not relevant to rapidity of spreading. It avoids them on purpose. Now, if there is something missing about how fast could it spread in oceans, I'll be glad to work on this question. If it belongs to follow ups, please wait.

Comment: In case you're interested, there's a (not-very-good by my dim memory) 1972 SF novel _Mutant 59: The Plastic-Eaters_, by Kit Pedler and Gerry Davis, with the premise of a plastic-eating microbe spreading worldwide. (Spoiler: doesn't turn out well.)

Comment: It doesn't have to travel in ocean currents, it just needs to hitch a ride on freighters.  That's a real-world problem right now - see things like https://ocean.si.edu/conservation/invasive-species/reducing-risk-transporting-invasive-species

Comment: A microbe that can eat (at the rate you seem to think about) solid plastic is highly unrealistic. They can't even eat wood easily, before some animal with very sharp teeth has ground it finely. Won't happen. So is a microbe that learns how to eat PE, PP; PVE, PMMA, PS all at the same time. Sorry. ;-) (I have read the paper about worms that eat PS foam and can actually digest it. Not the same thing.)

Comment: @Karl won't happen naturally, but don't forget it is about bioengineered microbes, and most plastic is already in nice thin sheets, 0.5mm for really thick plastic bags and bottles, often less.

Comment: @Mołot Even 0.05mm for a microbe is equivalent to a half-meter thick wall for you. Will take you a few hours to get through even if it is made  of plastic and not concrete. ;-)

Comment: you would have a very large spread quite quickly, and there would really be no getting rid of these microbes either

Answer (score 14):

The debris generated by the tsunami hitting Japan in 2011 reached US West coast, thus crossed the Pacific Ocean, after few months.

This is your upper limit for the needed time. Add to this that, as opposed to solid debris, bacterial spores can be transported by wind or animals, and your diffusion time significantly shortens.

I.e. take an albatross resting in an infected plastic patch in the middle of the ocean, it will carry the spores hundreds of kilometers away in a matter of few days. And the more they are spread, the further they can spread.

Comment: Oh. Birds. Good point!

Comment: Ever see the [The Satan Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Satan_Bug) as the plot is based on a deadly plague stolen from a secret lab.  Once quote is *"Perhaps the Great Albatross swinging its way around the bottom of the world. Perhaps an Eskimo deep in the Arctic. But the seas travel the world over, and so do the winds. One day, one day soon, they too would die."*

Answer (score 11):

The inventors of penicillin carried the mold out of Nazi territory by smearing it on their clothes.

If you want a quick dispersal, then consider human air travelers as your medium.

*The initial release was tiny. It might not have spread at all beyond this city of bricks and concrete except for John Smith, in town for the day on business. A few tiny spores landed on his down jacket as he walked past the bland building housing the lab. They blossomed inconspicuously on the inside of the jacket's bottom hem and released more spores among the feathers.*

*When John stuffed his coat into the overhead bin before takeoff from Beijing, an almost invisible puff of spores wafted down the aisle and into an intake that would spread slow destruction throughout the plane. That plane eventually fell out of the sky, oil gummed and worthless, plastic components rotted out. But not before it delivered John to Amsterdam, where he was deplaned onto the apron. The day was cold, so he fluffed the jacket out, spreading spores on several nearby airport workers, before putting it on and boarding the shuttle to the terminal. It was several minutes before the shuttle was fully loaded. In the process, John was jostled several times as the other passengers crammed onto the bus, to the effect that no human left that shuttle without being thoroughly infected. They would fly on to Paris, Frankfurt, Jakarta, Sao Paulo... And John continued his journey too, heading first to Washington D.C.'s Dulles International, and then on to Atlanta, the busiest airport in the world.*

Answer (score 0):

These days any microbe can travel **around the world in two days** thanks to humans. It only take one human with plastic lunchbox, umbrella, wallet, anything really, to hop on a plane and be in another continent the same day. Once the microbes reach all major population centers in two, maybe three days, they will spread somewhat more slowly into the countryside on busses, telephone line insulation, newspaper wraps, but in **couple of weeks** at most, they are **everywhere**.

Comment: This is really nice answer, but would benefit from some sources :)

Comment: sorry, but which parts need sourcing? :) long haul flights and ubiquity of plastics are common knowledge. How easy it is for the microbe to infect the plastic bottle in your bag is up to you in your story, but once they get out of the lab they will spread as i describe. your bottle doesn't need to touch the cable going out of your house, the same way your sandwich doesn't need to touch anything moldy to catch mold. all microbes are airborne, it's up to you how long they can survive in the air, but anything longer than couple of seconds is enough.

Comment: Now it is identical to this one: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/132553/809 I assumed it is meant to be different and you have some source for two days claim, like L.Dutch had for his [few months with oceanic currents answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/132503/809).